# R - ggplot command discontinuos values at x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot the number of exoplanets discovered per year, grouped by the method of discovery. My data is of this kind: planet|discovery method|year

I have this command:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=pl_disc, fill=pl_discmethod)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdBu") +
  labs(x="Years", y="Count", 
       title="Number of exoplanets discovered per year",  
       fill="Discovery method")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +   
  scale_x_continuous("Years", labels=data$pl_disc, breaks=data$pl_disc)
```

And getting this plot:

[image]

I need a little different version of this plot.

1. The years on the x-axis are incomplete. When there aren't values to plot for a given year, the year is not shown. I want all the years to be shown
2. I also need to show the sum of the elements in each column. I tried this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=pl_disc, fill=pl_discmethod)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdBu") + 
  stat_bin(aes(label=..count..),vjust=-1, geom="text", binwidth = 1) + 
  labs(x="Years", y="Count", 
       title="Number of exoplanets discovered per year", 
       fill="Discovery method")
```

But the values are overwritten, as seen in this plot:

[image]
How can I have the complete scale of years and the count of each column?

Comment: About the incomplete x axis: please check, which type pl_disc is - probably it's character or factor - so you might have to convert to date. And, a hint: here are some ideas how to prepare questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: pl_disc is the year, as is shown in the x axis

Comment: What does ```typeof(data$pl_disc)``` say?

Comment: Is an integer.-

Comment: That seems OK - the reason then might be that you've specified the breaks to be from your source data ```scale_x_continuous("Years", labels=data$pl_disc, breaks=data$pl_disc)```- so, if there are years missing, they don't show up. If you ```dput(data)``` or a subset ```dput(data[10,]```) it would be easier to re-run your code.

Comment: Couldn't make in work. I obtain the same plot using dput. But how can I get the count of each column?

Comment: Sorry I was too short in comment:with dput I meant: please make a dump of your data and add to your question, then others can copy it easily into their R and try to run your code.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your plot with some example data - I didn't get the effect with the missing years. For the labels you could try ```stat_bin(aes(label=..count..), geom="text", binwidth = 1, position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5))```

Comment: I already tried that for the counts and the values are overwriten in the columns (I attached an image) and I run:ggplot(data, aes(x=pl_disc, fill=pl_discmethod)) + geom_bar() + scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdBu")+labs(x="Years", y="Count", title="Number of exoplanets discovered per year", fill="Discovery method")+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) + scale_x_continuous("Years", labels=data$pl_disc, breaks=data$pl_disc)+stat_bin(aes(label=..count..), geom="text", binwidth = 1, position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5))

Comment: This is part of the data:
loc_rowid pl_name pl_discmethod pl_disc
1 11 Com b Radial Velocity 2007
2 11 UMi b Radial Velocity 2009
3 14 And b Radial Velocity 2008
4 14 Her b Radial Velocity 2002
5 16 Cyg B b Radial Velocity 1996
6 18 Del b Radial Velocity 2008
7 1RXS J160929.1-210524 b Imaging 2008